# D7: file_create_url() usable in node.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, nodes

Can you use `file_create_url()` inside node.tpl.php? Should I assume you can only use it in the template.php?

```
$img_src = render($content['field_image']);
$bgimage = file_create_url($img_src);
```

Using the following code, I am only getting `public://science-of-rock_background.png` from `$img_src`.
Is there any reason why it would be blank?

```
print $img_src;
print $bgimage;
```

---

**Edit made to avoid confusion:**

In my tpl page for this field I am generating the uri.

**field--field_image.tpl.php**

```
<?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item) : ?>
  <?php 
  print $item['#item']['uri']; 
  ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd first suggest to dpm($img_src)  -- You'll need the devel module for that to work. See what is actually inside that field. It's odd that it would be a file path though.

I'd never put logic like that inside a template file anyway. Use a preprocess function anyway:

```
template_preprocess_node(&$variables) {


}
```

inside template.php (replace template with your theme name)

Comment: Interesting. Silly question. How would I directly pull the field into this? render($content['field_image']); doesn't work. Would it be the full array?

Comment: Another question, on using dpm(). Can you 'only' use it in a function in the template.php?

Comment: (Cliché -- there are no silly questions!)
The field values will be inside that $variables array. Use dpm($variables) and hopefully you'll see a yellow box that contains the values of that array.

2. You can use dpm anywhere there is a messages region in your theme. An alternative is kpr. That basically does the same thing but injects the debug text at the top of the page.

Comment: Got it. 1 and 2 both worked. Thanks a ton for the help!

Answer (score 2):

`file_create_url` takes a uri, such as `public://science-of-rock_background.png`

The revised:

`$img_src = $content['field_image'];
$bgimage = file_create_url($img_src);`

Would work if your field is only returning the URI.

And, for best practices, should set that up in preprocess_node, otherwise will work in node.tpl.php

Comment: The content of the field is available as `$field_image`; `$content['field_image']` is always a rendering array, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: The file's URI is available within the render array, and the code was shortened based on OP stating: I am only getting public://science-of-rock_background.png from $img_src

Comment: Sure, it is available, but you need to access it more directly than with `$content['field_image']`. It is then an error to use the render array when the field content is already available.

Comment: And you are completely correct. Was trying to keep in context of original post - I know this is exactly how i started, and then moved into proper format

Answer (score 0):

The error is that `render()` returns HTML output, while `file_create_url()` is expecting a URI or a file path. In [node.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7), the content of a field is available as variable; so, the field you are trying to access is available as `$field_image`, basing on the following note.

> Field variables: for each field instance attached to the node a corresponding variable is defined; for example, `$node->body` becomes `$body`. When needing to access a field's raw values, developers/themers are strongly encouraged to use these variables. Otherwise they will have to explicitly specify the desired field language; for example, `$node->body['en']`, thus overriding any language negotiation rule that was previously applied.